# Access JSON array in serde_json::Value

Tags: json, rust, serde, serde-json

I have some JSON formatted like this:

```json
[
    {
        "name": "jsonvalue"
    }
]
```

And I want to print it like `println!("{:?}", json["name"]);`. How do I access a JSON array from a serde_json::Value?

I would like to not have to use more variables to break it down is the point.

Answer (score -1):

You can access an element from a JSON array by the index operator `[0]`:

```
let value = json!([{"name":"jsonvalue"}]);
println!("{}", value[0]["name"]);
```

```
"jsonvalue"
```

Note that the index operator will panic if the element doesn't exist, but you can use [`.get()`](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/enum.Value.html#method.get) to handle that case since it returns an `Option`.